# I'm from the UK and think I might have overstayed in the USA

Tags: usa, esta, b1-b2-visas, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I am going to the usa in April and ive applied for a esta visa though the waiver programme and got it approved but what im concerned about is around 12-13 years ago  i think i might have over stayed the waiver programme at the time but i can not remember that far back and my passport has been renewed and i dont have the old passport at all anymore , will i have any problems with border control, immigration at all , when i filled out the esta visa and the question have up , have i over stayed at all i answered no because to my knowledge i have not and can not remember  the dates from 12-13 years ago so i have answered honestly to the best i can remember .

Also i was informed about a b1/b2 travel visa and applied for that and not im told i dont need it will cancelling my appointment affect anything as i have already been approved for a esta visa though the waiver programme.

I'm a United Kingdom citizen.

Comment: Why do you think you may have overstayed?  What do you remember about that trip?

Comment: Nobody knows what will happen.

Comment: If you don't know we don't know